# Changing video content swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with some UIImage, I want to put two videos using `MPMoviePlayerController` (I know its deprecated) but if I use more than two videos the second one stop to play because the Apple DOC says it's impossible to start at the same time more than one video. So I want to keep the same Media Player but with different content. 
But I can't replace the content.

```
var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?

   func firstVideo(path:String){

  var audioplayer : MPMoviePlayerController!
        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("airplane", ofType:"m4v")      
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)        
        self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        let player = self.moviePlayer

        if let player = self.moviePlayer {

            player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

            player.view.sizeToFit()
            player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill
            player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
            player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One

          self.view.addSubview(player.view)

        }
    }

  func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){


        var pageheight = self.scrollView.frame.size.width
        var page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageheight / 2) / pageheight) + 1;

        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(page);


        if (page == 1.0){



            if let player = moviePlayer{

                player.play()

            }

            }



        else if (page == 2.0){
            if let player = moviePlayer{

                player.stop()

            }
        }

        if (page == 3.0){
            if let player = moviePlayer{

 var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("another_video", ofType:"m4v")
                firstVideo(path!)

                player.play()           
            }
        }


        else{
            if let player = moviePlayer{

               player.stop()

                // playerTwo.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in design from this scrollview? If you want to show the player at each page then you need to change the frame of player when you scroll and pass the path of content to your play method.

Comment: can you leave a part of code?

Comment: What is your clear requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using `UITableView` instead of `UIScrollView` ? So, you can use only one `MPMoviePlayerController` object with multiple contents in each cell.

Also, you get new bundle URL for your next `MPMoviePlayerController` object and send it your player function but you create new object named 'path' again in this function and never use `path` object which send. So your video path is always same. Try this;

```
if (page == 3.0){

   if let player = moviePlayer{

      let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("another_video", ofType:"m4v")      
      player.contentURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!) 
      player.play()           
   }
}
```